# Fitting ImageButton in a Table

Tags: android, android-layout, imagebutton

I'm trying to create a table with 4 cells, each row has 2 `ImageButton` in it.
For some reason the `ImageButton` seems to be to wide and exit the screen even though the `tablerow` width is `match parent`

**Here's the Code:**

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" >
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"    

   >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button4"
            android:background="@null"
            android:onClick="changepic2"

            android:src="@drawable/breakingdawn"
            android:text="Breaking Dawn" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="@null"
            android:onClick="changepic3"

            android:src="@drawable/newmoon" />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:onClick="changepic"

            android:paddingTop="2dp"

            android:src="@drawable/twilight"
            android:background="@null"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:onClick="changepic1"

            android:src="@drawable/eclipse"
            android:paddingTop="2dp"
            android:background="@null" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Any idea how can i make it fit in screen exactly?

Thanks!! :)

Comment: Instead of this `android:src="@drawable/eclipse"`  use `android:background="@drawable/eclipse"` and try once

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

**this** `android:src="@drawable/eclipse"`

**use** `android:background="@drawable/eclipse"`

and try once. it might help you

and use `wrapcontent` instead of `matchparent`

Comment: Thanks but it didn't work, still same results, the buttons on the right side of the screen exit the screen

Comment: did you removed `android:background="@null"` this and tried with above thing? because that is working for me